# Double integral: Stokes' theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, line-integrals, surface-integrals

[image]

Honestly, I have no idea what Stokes' theorem is. I only know that the circulation can be found by this theorem. Would anyone mind helping me?

Answer (score 3):

Stokes' theorem relates a surface integral (of a curl) to a line integral over the boundary of the surface. This means you can simplify some of the integrals by translating surface integral to a line integral or vice-versa. In essence, it's just a higher-dimensional version of the fundamental theorem of calculus: an integral of derivative (now curl) over an interval (now a surface) equals the value of the function (now a vector field) at the boundaries (now a line, so we still need another integral). See also the Gauss' theorem which does this for a 3D volume.

Now, just calculate the curl:
$$\vec{F}=(z^2,y^2,x)$$
$$\nabla\times \vec{F}=(0,2z-1,0)$$
An integral ofer a triangle should be quite simple: you just need to figure out a normal (hint: it's along (1,1,1) due to symmetry) and choose appropriate coordinates to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Thanks. Is the answer $-1/6$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Stokes' theorem relates the circulation along a closed curve with the integral of a quantity known as "curl" over some surface where the given curve is the boundary, at each point multiplied with the unit normal vector of the surface.

In your case, the curve can be seen as a triangle contained in a plane with normal vector $(1,1,1)$, so if you normalise that you get your $\hat n$. The quantity in brackets is the cross product of the "vector"
$$
\nabla = \left(\frac{d}{dx},\frac{d}{dy},\frac{d}{dz}\right)
$$ with the vector field $\vec F$.

Comment: Thanks, but what are upper limits and lower limits of the integration? I am confused.

Comment: @user100523 to actually insert lower and upper limits, you need to first do a substitution so that you only have two coordinates to work with (instead of the three coordinates in $\Bbb R^3$). This is usually done by finding a parameterization of the triangle. Have you ever done surface integrals before? Like integrating over the boundary of the unit sphere? That's a skill you will need a lot if you're working with Stoke's and Gauss' theorems.